# bigquery stored procedure delete statement removes rows it shouldn't

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I use a Stored Procedure to execute a `DELETE` statement with a `WHERE` clause, the clause seems to be ignored.

Steps to reproduce:

### Create the BQ table

```
CREATE TABLE `[project].[dataset].test` (
   email STRING NOT NULL,
   providerId STRING NOT NULL
);
```

### Add test data

```
insert into `[project].[dataset].test` (email, providerId) values ('test.email@gmail.com', 'test1');
insert into `[project].[dataset].test` (email, providerId) values ('test.email@gmail.com', 'test2');
```

### Create a Stored Procedure that takes `email` and `providerId` as input

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `[project].[dataset].RemovePermission`(IN providerId STRING, IN email STRING)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM `[project].[dataset].test` p
  WHERE       p.email = email
              AND p.providerId = providerId;
END;
```

### Execute the Stored Procedure

```
CALL [project].[dataset].RemovePermission('test1', 'test.email@gmail.com`)
```

Notice that the response is 2 lines removed, and the test table is now empty.

Conversely, if you execute the delete manually, as below, only 1 row is removed - this is the correct behavior.

```
DELETE FROM `[project].[dataset].test` p
  WHERE       p.email = 'test.email@gmail.com'
              AND p.providerId = 'test1';
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments names `email, providerId` are "conflicting" with columns names `email, providerId` and thus `WHERE p.email = email AND p.providerId = providerId` is ALWAYS `true`

Just change arguments name and it should work as expected. Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project.dataset.RemovePermission`(IN Id STRING, IN txt STRING)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM `project.dataset.test` p
  WHERE p.email = txt
  AND p.providerId = Id;
END;
```

Comment: Well that's unexpected :) Thanks. I was assuming that aliasing the table makes it unambiguous.